# Issue with Optionals in Swift when using dispatch_async()

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, option-type

Hey guys I am very inexperienced with Swift so I am sure this problem is from me being naive to syntax. In general I am trying to retrieve data from Parse and read the results into a `NSArray`. However, I get the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have narrowed it down to this section in the code at which the function fails. I get the error just after the `self.userData = res` line. I am sure that I am unwrapping a nil value as stated but don't know how to fix it. If I do something like `var res = query!.findObjects()?` to make findObjects optional then I get a compiler error. Just a little stuck, anything helps.

```
func getUserInfo() {
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        let user = PFUser.currentUser()
        var query = PFUser.query()
        query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: self.username)
        var res = query!.findObjects()!
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.userData = res
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to start removing the `1` key from the keyboards of Swift programmers so they might stop abusing the `!` operator...

Answer (score 3):

It's much more likely to be one of these lines:

```
    query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: self.username)
    var res = query!.findObjects()!
```

Those are the lines that unwrap `Optional` values.

Try this instead:

```
if let unwrappedQuery = query {
    unwrappedQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: self.username)
    if let result = query.findObjects() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.userData = result
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    } else {
        println("query.findObjects returned nil")
    }
} else {
    println("query was nil")
}
```